# Displaying a URL in a UITableViewCell in a different color from the rest of the text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working through the Stanford iPhone programming course online.  The Presence app assignment pulls Twitter and displays each one in a separate UITableViewCell.

Updates often include URL's and I'd like to know how to display just the URL text in blue, having it be tappable.  I can parse the text for URL's with no problem, just no idea how to display the URL itself.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above a button would work, but in terms of the UI it would probably look more natural if you had a label.

Alternatively, you could fill the UITableViewCell with a UIWebView.  The UIWebView would hold all the text and you should easily be able to set part of the text as a link (color blue) using html.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a UIButton (or something similar) to the cell, with the button title being the URL and the action opening the actual link.